# How to create a custom "boundary / background" between 2 children of a column in flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout, responsive-design

I've had a specific requirement from my designer regarding a simple layout, but with some kind of complex graphic design. The layout is mainly a Column holding 2 children widgets (with some padding, etc...).

What is asked is to have (see image below for illustration):

- a custom shape as the backgroung of the first child. The boundary of this background both extends inside and outside this first child bounding box, and extends over the height of the second child
- no background whatsoever for the second child
- as this layout will be reused in many places in the app, it should be kind of dynamic, and adjust to the actual height of child #1. The background shape should not be flattened or extended, but rather only translated up and down the frame (i.e. like if the red dot in the image below would serve as an anchor for the background shape, moving up and down depending on how high is the child #1).

[image: an image depicting the required layout]

What I thought about doing:

- defining the background shape as a custom painter from the Path I got from the designer
- put the background shape and the Column inside a Stack
- and somehow manage to adjust the position of the background shape to the height of the first child of the column, as well as clipping it to the screen of the phone.

Any help or resource is welcome regarding this topic.

Regards,

Comment: you need a column with two children, the first is `CustomPaint` and the second is your second child: `Column[CustomPaint > Child1, Child2]` - with that a `CustomPaint` widget will always match `Child1` size

Comment: Thanks for this comment @pskink, I will look into it. However, will it enable to have the background shape extend over the height of the second child? (the left part of the background shape, I just edited my question to be clearer about it)

Comment: "will it enable to have the background shape extend over the height of the second child?" yes

Comment: Nice! I will try it and let you know!

Comment: You can simply use the background image and then put whatever layout you want on it.

Comment: Hi @pskink, I did implement it the way you suggested, and it worked like a charm! I will post my code for further reference, but if you would post your comment as an answer I would gladly mark it as accepted. Regards, Pierre

Comment: it's great it worked, feel free to post a self answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @pskink comment, I did manage to build the layout according to the exact requirements stated in my question.

The main takeaway is that a `CustomPainter` can somehow paint outside its `Size` parameter and therefore "overflow" its child borders.

Please see my code below, well as the final result:

```
class ProfileWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileWidget({super.key, required this.profile});

  final Caregiver profile;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (ListView.separated(
      itemCount: 1 + (profile.helpees == null ? 0 : profile.helpees!.length),
      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
        if (index == 0) {
          return (_ProfileMainInfo(profile: profile));
        } else {
          return (_ProfileHelpee(helpee: profile.helpees?[index - 1]));
        }
      }),
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        double? dividerHeight = index == 0 ? 50.0 : null;
        return (SizedBox(
          height: dividerHeight,
        ));
      },
    ));
  }
}

class _ProfileMainInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ProfileMainInfo({required this.profile});

  final Caregiver profile;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _WaveBackgroundPainter(),
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _ProfileTitle(profile: profile),
            _ProfileImage(profile: profile),
            _ProfileTags(profile: profile),
            (profile.helperBio == null)
                ? Container()
                : Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextBio(text: profile.helperBio!),
                  ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class _WaveBackgroundPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = elpyooColorYellow;

    const double waveHeight = 150;
    final topPartHeight = size.height * .83;

    final Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, topPartHeight);
    path.cubicTo(
        size.width,
        topPartHeight + waveHeight * 0.39,
        size.width * 0.84,
        topPartHeight + waveHeight * 0.86,
        size.width / 2,
        topPartHeight + waveHeight * 0.6);
    path.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.16,
        topPartHeight + waveHeight * 0.35,
        size.width * 0.02,
        topPartHeight + waveHeight * 0.85,
        0,
        topPartHeight + waveHeight);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(
      path,
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image: the final version of the design]